# Port Number in Appharbor URL causes page/content not to load

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, appharbor, requestreduce

On AppHarbor, generating the current absolute URL in the standard Asp .Net way produces a URL of the format:

```
scheme://[domain]:[port]/path
```

When accessed from a browser, this URL fails - **removing the port number fixes this**.

I'm fairly confident this wasn't always the case, and this change is now causing an issue with my apps.

I understand I can use a helper method to create the URL correctly, however, in 3rd party plugins (RequestReduce for example), this isn't possible to control.

Does anyone know a way to change this globally, Such that port numbers are never generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding [this module](http://nuget.org/packages/Premotion.AspNet.AppHarbor.Integration) to your project.

We're looking at adding something similar on all AppHarbor servers to avoid the various workarounds people currently use.

Comment: Thanks friism - I didn't realise you'd released this package and was still using my own workarounds to build absolute URL's. This seems to work perfectly after my initial tests - thanks!

Comment: Note that's it not something we've built - but we probably should have :-)

Comment: This seems to throw up a new problem - Request.IsAjaxRequest() - no longer returns true. Is it because the headers are now being stripped out?

Comment: Seems to be that the native helper method is overridden by the module you suggested, such that "IsAjax" is never set.

Comment: Should have mentioned, put in a pull request and my changes are now part of the module. Any other headers you think could be effected by this? I need to find time to run some proper tests!

Comment: Awesome that you got the fix in! No other troublesome headers spring to mind immediately.

Comment: should this have fixed my issue with RequestReduce? If so, it didn't work... (https://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce/issues/215)